# Why is a highlighted % being appended to the output of printf?

Tags: c, printf, stdio

When I print a string with `printf` like in the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    printf("Foo");
}
```

In the output, I get the following:

[image]

As seen in this picture, there is a highlighted percent sign placed after the output of `printf`. What's causing this? How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's your shell's prompt.  You're not printing a newline after the string "Foo", so the prompt appears immediately after it.

Add a newline to the string to print so the shell prompt appears on a separate line.

```
printf("Foo\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the `%` is your terminal's prompt. Your program doesn't output a newline, so the next prompt would not appear on a new line.